# 'this' inside of a BukkitRunnable

Tags: java, oop, scope, minecraft, bukkit

What does the `this` keyword refer to inside an `org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable`?

```
public class Foo {
  protected Player player;

  public Foo(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
    BukkitRunnable runnable = new BukkitRunnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // does 'this' still refer to the instance of 'Foo' ?
        this.player.sendMessage("Hello");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Would the above runnable send a message to the player used to instantiate that `Foo`?

Comment: Why don't you try `System.out.println(this.getClass().getName())` and find out yourself?

Comment: *does 'this' still refer to the instance of 'Foo' ?* no, but `Foo.this` does. `this` refers to the instance of `BukkitRunnable`. In your case you could just omit `this` all together since the parameter `player` is implicitly final as its value is never modified (assuming Java 8 or you could make the parameter `player` `final` pre Java 8). In your example it makes no difference whether you use `player` or `Foo.this.player` since they both reference to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside a `BukkitRunnable` refers to the `BukkitRunnable` instance you created.
In this case, simply referring to `player` is enough.
Otherwise, use `OuterClass.this` to refer to the currnet instance from an inner class. In this case you would use `Foo.this.player` to get the player.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is referring to the instance of `BukkitRunnable` that you created. If you want to send the player a message, you must reference your `Foo` instance instead of referencing your `BukkitRunnable` instance.

You can do so by using `Foo.this`. So

```
Foo.this.player.sendMessage("Hello");
```

Might be what you're looking for.

But as you're using an anonymous inner class, you can access any `final` variable from it's scope, therefore you can just reference `player`, without any `this` keyword.

```
player.sendMessage("hello"); //inside BukkitRunnable
```

As pointed out by @d.j.brown, Java 8 infers `player` immutability, and you don't need to add the `final` keyword to it.

Comment: I actually have a subclass of Foo that sets its own `this.player`. Would using `Foo.this.player` get the correct property of the subclass instance?